# A simple application of contraction mapping principle

Tags: real-analysis

> Let X and Y be metric spaces. Let $f : X → Y$ be uniformly continuous. Prove that if $x_n$ is a Cauchy
>   sequence in X, then $f(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in Y.
>
> Then, show that if Y is complete, E ⊂ X is dense, and $f_0 : E → Y$ is uniformly continuous, then there is a unique continuous function$ f : X → Y$ such that $f |_E = f_0$.

I can finish the first part. Can somebody help with the second part?

I guess it should use contraction mapping theorem..

Answer (score 0):

For each $x\in X$ pick a sequence $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $E$ convergent to $x$. Then $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$. Hence $\{f_0(e_n)\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$. Since $Y$ is complete, there exists a limit

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}f_0(e_n) = y$$

Define $f(x) = y$. Check that it does not depend on the choice of $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and that $f_{\mid E} = f_0$.

**Remark.**

This holds for arbitrary uniform spaces. Let $X$ be a uniform space and let $E$ be its dense subspace (this means that $X$ is contained in the uniform completion of $E$). Let $f_0:E\rightarrow Y$ be a uniform map to a complete uniform space. Then it admits a unique extension $f:X\rightarrow Y$.